# Change font size of embedded object

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I have a web page with an embedded text file. The text file is named "Broadcast.txt" and it has .LOG at the top line to enter a timestamp each time it is opened. Other than that is has no other special features.I cannot find how to change the displayed font for the embedded object. I have looked in Dreamweaver to find any setting that would let us display a larger font, to no avail. Here is a snippet of the code I have: I have tried to change the font to 42pt and it still do effect. I tried changing the setting in CSS and it still will not affect change to the small displayed font. Any ideas?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header"><a href="#"><img src="" alt="Insert Logo Here" name="Insert_logo" width="180" height="90" id="Insert_logo" style="background: #C6D580; display:block;" /></a> 
    <!-- end .header --></div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
<h2>&nbsp;</h2>
    <p>  <OBJECT DATA="Broadcast.txt" TYPE="text/html" WIDTH="600" HEIGHT="400" ALIGN="bottom" STYLE="width:96%;margin:2%;">
        <EMBED SRC="U:\Web Pages\Web Templates\greeny_blu\Broadcast.txt" WIDTH="600" HEIGHT="400" ALIGN="bottom"></EMBED>
      </OBJECT> </p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <!-- end .content --></div>
```

Ok, what about doing it this way? I am reading it in thru JS, it is in a frame now. I still cannot isolate the font. Here is what I have :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
  <title>ISC Impact Summary</title>
  <!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
  <META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="10"> <!--
  This is the automatic refresh setting for this web page. It is in seconds. 
  -->
  <html>  
  <style type="text/css">
  body {
    background-color: #06F;
  }
  .Style1 {
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 24em;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
}
  body,td,th {
    color: #CF0;
}
  </style>
  <head>  
  <script type="text/javascript">   
  function init(){      
  var extText = window.frames[0].document.getElementsByTagName("HTML")[0].outerHTML; 
  document.getElementById("nMessage").innerText = extText; }
  </script>
  <!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="head" -->
  <!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
  </head>  
  <body>
  <div>
    <div align="center">
      <h2>ISC Critical Alert Summary</h2>
    </div>
  </div>


   <div>
  </div>
  <div align="center" style="font-size:42;"><!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="EditRegion1" -->
  <iframe src="Broadcast.txt" width="96%" marginwidth="2%" height="400" marginheight="2%" align="middle"     scrolling="Yes" class="Style1" id="messageTxt" style="font-size:42pt" >ISC Critical status</iframe>
    <!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
  </div>   </body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change any parameters from "main" html. Browsers isolates iframes and embedded docs from parent.

You can load text via javascript or use html rather than txt.

---

**TECH DETAILS** :)

t.txt - is file with text. You can set for it full url or place it near this page and set only it name.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ISC Impact Summary</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .b-box_with_grand_text{
            font-size: 42px;
        }
    </style>
    <!--copy this block. jQuery is get from google servers-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // this possible write on clean JS
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.get('t.txt', function(data) {
                // #echo_file = id from div
                $('#echo_file').html(data);
                alert('Load was performed.');
            });
        })
    </script>
    <!--end copy-->
</head>
<body>
<!--in this block txt file content will be posted. 
Just copy id in place where you want place text-->
<div id="echo_file" class="b-box_with_grand_text"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This works but it load expensive library jQuery.

Comment: Ok, what about doing it this way then. I am reading it in thru JS, it it in a frame now. I still cannot isolate the font. Here is what I have done now:

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience but I mean read it with JS and put to div (span or etc) with needed formatting

Comment: I have two comments of what I cannot do, does anyone have any suggestions of how I might do what I am trying to accomplish in a little more technical detail?

Comment: Tech details looks like an answer that I can work with, however it does not function from within Dreamweaver when saved as a html page. Does this require that jQuery be installed?

Comment: jQuery is downloaded from google servers so you dont needed to download it.

Comment: I update example add some comments.
This example work on normal webserver.
I don't try this solution locally. 
About Dreamwiever - I newer take it seriosly. I prefer text editors with autocomplete