# Changing font size of embedded text files?

Tags: html, css, fonts, text-files, font-size

I can't seem to figure out how to change the font size of an embedded text file, style doesn't work for some reason. No matter what I try nothing happens.

```
<style>
pre {
  font-family: "Courier New", monospace;
  font-size: 50px;
}
object {
  font-family: "Courier New", monospace;
  font-size: 50px;
}
body {
  font-family: "Courier New", monospace;
  font-size: 50px;
}
</style>

<body>
  <pre class="tab" id="Display">
  <object width="12000" height="12000" type="text/css" data="textFiles/file.txt" border="0" >
  </pre>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change any parameters from "main" html. Browsers isolates iframes and embedded docs from parent.

You can load text via javascript or use html rather than txt.

Here is the original answer:

[Change font size of embedded object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369770/change-font-size-of-embedded-object)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30171831)